# Combine many repeated copies of few PDFs into a small file

Tags: command-line, unix, pdf

To generate a class set of worksheets, their solutions, and quizzes of different versions, I create "print packs" of repeated PDF files.

These I generate with

```
pdfjam -o print_pack.pdf WS.pdf ... WS.pdf WS-solution.pdf ... WS-solution.pdf Quiz.pdf ... Quiz.pdf
```

where each of `WS.pdf`, `WS-solution.pdf`, and `Quiz.pdf` is repeated N times, where N is the class size.

The resulting PDF file thus contains really only three different PDF files, however, its size grows substantially with N. My N ranges from 30 to 65 and I need multiple (different versions) of these, and then email them, hence the size restriction.

Is there a better way that is less dependent on N? I.e., can I somehow keep the file size down?

I was thinking to utilise the object-oriented nature of the PDF standard in order to reference included files rather then to effectively repeat them, but I cannot seem to find a tool that does this. Any suggestions welcome!